# jquery deferred in .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, deferred

This should be a simple one.
I have a function that is called and I need to wait for all the async operations to complete.
what I want is something like this...

```
self.processSchema(data).done(function(results){ //do stuff});
```

The processSchema function loops using $.each and calls an async method.

```
var processSchema = function(data)
{
     var def = new $.Deferred();
     $.each(table, function()
     {
         //calls an async SQLitePlugin method
         db.executeSql(sql, data, function(tx, results){
            def.resolve(results);
         }
     }

     return(def.promise());
}
```

This does not seem to work, I am new to $.Deferred so any guidance would be helpful

Comment: I think you would need a new deferred for every single db.executeSql, and then do a large $.when(deferred1, deferred2...defferedN).then(function(data1, data2...dataN) {  });

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll need a promise for each iteration

```
var processSchema = function(data) {
     var promises = [];

     $.each(table, function() {
         var def = new $.Deferred();
         db.executeSql(sql, data, function(tx, results){
            def.resolve(results);
         });
         promises.push(def);
     });

     return $.when.apply(undefined, promises).promise();
}
```

Comment: adeneo, should that return defcon.promise() ?

Comment: Yes it should! One could return the array of promises, but to keep the syntax of how the OP want's to call the function, I figure one master promise that is returned and then resolved when all the other promises are resolved would be easier, and then pass all the returned data as the arguments array directly ?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, so the def.apply will work inside of loop?

Comment: @adeneo actually you can simply return result of `$.when`, without creating "master" promise?

Comment: @hawk Because you actually *want* to return a Promise, not a Deferred. Because Promises are read-only.

Comment: @gdex `apply` takes an array and uses it as a list of arguments. `$.when` takes a list of promises and returns a promise that resolves when all arguments resolve

Comment: @Tomalak `$.when.apply(...).promise()`

Comment: @hawk - indeed you could, as chaining `done` on the function call would be the same as chaining `then` on the `$.when`, and as Jan points out, just adding `promise()` returns the promise and would be the same as the master deferred.

Comment: For what it's worth, it would be safer to pass `$` as the context to `apply`. We don't know if `$.when` uses `this` internally, but if it does we want it pointing to `$`, hence `$.when.apply($, promises).promise()`.

Comment: Using the `apply().then` gives me an argument array of each deferred result which may be helpful in my scenario. The `.promise()` only returns the last result which is fine in some cases. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @gdex - that's actually true, then() would return an array of results, which could be useful.

Answer (score 8):

For Functional Programming fiends (like myself), here's a single-expression version of [adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20688889/1042595):

```
var processSchema = function(data) {
    return $.when.apply($, $.map(table, function() {
        var def = new $.Deferred();
        db.executeSql(sql, data, function(tx, results){
            def.resolve(results);
        });
        return def;
    })).promise();
};
```

Also I'd like to note that you are iterating over `table`, but aren't doing anything with each item in the iteration (i.e. the callback in your `each` has no arguments.) Now, I'm not sure what your goal is, but this doesn't seem right to me :P

Comment: There is a lot more to the function then I posted, for brevity I did not include some of the non essential stuff...