# node promise for loop wait for result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

How can I wait for the for loop to go to next loop?

How can I make sure that the userdetails is executed and realresult.playername is assigned to the new variable before passing it on ?

code:

```
return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {

    arr = [];


    messages.find({convid: convid}).then(function(result) {

        for(var a in result) {
            realresult = result[a];

            userData.userDetails(realresult.userid).then(function (result) {
                realresult.playername = result.username;
            });
            userData.usercashinfo(realresult.userid).then(function (resulttwo) {
                realresult.playerdetails = resulttwo;
            });

            arr.push(realresult);

        }

        return resolve(arr);
    });
});
```

Comment: use `Promise.all` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Daniel_L i dont know how i would remake my function to make it work with that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript for loop Promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701957/javascript-for-loop-promises)

Comment: i dont see how that would help me out @Roberrrt

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write a promise that, when it resolves, returns the array of resolved promise values. There are 2 things you should do here:

1. Use `return` to await the completion of a promise. In a promise chain, nothing actually resolves the promise value unless it is `return`ed. (You should also use this for `message.find()` since it's also giving you a promise.)
2. Construct the array as an array of promises, rather than iterating and having the promises push into the array when they resolve.
3. Use `Promise.all()` to collect the promise objects - `all()` returns only after all of the promises passed to it have resolved.
4. (optional) Don't reuse the `result` variable name to mean multiple things. It's not wrong here, but it can cause unnecessary confusion.

Put together, this would look something like:

```
return messages.find(...).then(function(result) {
  var promiseArr = [];
  for (var a in result) {
    promiseArr.push(
      promise.all([userData.userDetails(...), userData.usercashinfo(...)])
      .then(function(detailinfo) {
        var realresult = result[a];
        var details = detailinfo[0];
        var cashinfo = detailinfo[1];
        realresult.playername = details.username;
        realresult.playerdetails = cashinfo;
        return realresult;
    });
  }
  return Promise.all(promiseArr);
});
```

Comment: hey @yoz , i updated my post, could you make some edits to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

so I thought it is a good idea trying solving it with the combination of generators and promises, I'm not sure that its the best way to go, but Its a good practice for the combination of the two so I gave it a try.

The idea is that the generator function is waiting for the callback function before starting a new iteration and the callback function is waiting for both promises to complete before telling the generator function to go on iterating.

[here is a more simple example that I first tried on codepen](http://codepen.io/naortor/pen/KgVKzx)

```
return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    arr = [];
    messages.find({convid: convid}).then(function(result) {
        function* iterations() {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                realresult = result[i];
                try {
                    var cbResult = yield cb(result[i].userid);
                    realresult.playername = cbResult.playername;
                    realresult.playerdetails = cbResult.playerdetails;
                    arr.push(realresult);
                } catch (e) { reject(e) }
            }
            return arr.value;
        }

        var it = iterations();
        it.next();

        function cb(userid) {
            Promise.all([
                       userData.userDetails(userid),
                       userData.usercashinfo(userid)
                       ]).then(
                           function(values) {
                               var realresult = {playername : values[0], playerdetails : values[1]}
                               returnValue = it.next(realresult);
                               if (returnValue.done) {
                                   resolve(returnValue);
                               }
                           },
                           function(e) { reject(e) }
                       );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: This code is quite convoluted and doesn't handle any errors. Instead of using generators you should just go for `async`/`await`.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ch6i49 i did what you did @naortor, but then it wont return the array in plain response? as [0] and [1] ?

Comment: @Bergi , what would the best in this case be?

Comment: @maria I edited the answer so it will return the array as you want. but its more of a POC - as Bergi said it does't handle errors yet - you should wrap the yield call in a try / catch block and reject out errors from the promise

Comment: could we take a chat @naortor ?

Comment: This task can be easily handle by async module

Comment: sure, send me an invite cuz i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @abdulbarik The `async` module is of no help for promise-returning methods